# How to remove box around button?

Tags: html, css

i have `<input type = "button" id = "enterButton"/>` and decorate it with code below. But there appears a grey square around image. Is there anyway to remove it?

```
#enterButton{
    width: 45px;  
    min-width: 45px;
    min-height: 45px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    background-image: url("../img/logo3.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -ms-background-size: 100%;
    -khtml-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the background color setting:

```
background-color:white;
```

Or red or blue or transparent.. whatever you need it to be.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9U4EZ/)

Comment: Wouldn't that make a whole square area to respond on user clicks? Additionally, if i use script on hover for decorations the whole (now invisible area) will trigger it, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can add:

```
background: transparent;
```

Or any color you want to use.

Comment: Wouldn't that make a whole square area to respond on user clicks? Additionally, if i use script on hover for decorations the whole (now invisible area) will trigger it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
background-color: transparent;
```

to your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `background-color: transparent;` this issue will be resolved

```
#enterButton{
width: 45px;  
min-width: 45px;
min-height: 45px;
margin-left: 3%;
background-image: url("../img/logo3.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border: none;
-webkit-background-size: 100%;
-o-background-size: 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100%;
-ms-background-size: 100%;
-khtml-background-size: 100%;
background-size: 100%;
background-color: transparent; /* ADD THIS */
}
```

To make the button hover add this in the CSS

```
#enterButton:hover {
background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to css file or use inline css

```
background:transparent;
border:none;
```